# HTTP Error 503 with is Static compression is being disabled

Tags: iis

I'm show event log on windows log
The directory specified for caching compressed content C:\Users\Dat_PC\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.

How to fix ? Thanks everyone :(((

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735199(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @Sujith , i forget restart pc to apply setting, thanks :D.

Answer (score 1):

Check RouteConfig.cs make sure your route controller name equal to your MVC Controller name is match

Answer (score 1):

Usually it comes as a warning in event viewer. In IIS, static content compression can be enabled in two levels.

1. site level
2. IIS level

Site level you don't have an option to change path. But at the IIS level you can enable and change the path as you needed.

Enable/Disable : Click on the root node of IIS. > At the right content panel > Double click on the "Compression" option. > You may change as needed from the check boxes

[image]